# Firefox "Bookmark This Page" dialog disabled

Tags: macos, firefox, bookmarks

For some weeks now, the "Bookmark This Page" dialog stopped appearing. When I try to add a new bookmark using `Cmd+d` It automatically adds it somewhere; usually the Bookmarks Toolbar or the Bookmarks Menu. The same thing happens when I try to add a bookmark in any other way (clicking on the little star in the awesome bar, using the menu item, etc).

I have been trying to figure out where the problem comes from without success. Does anyone know how I could re-enable the "Bookmark This Page" dialog please?

Here is the list of extensions that I have installed along with some user agent info:

```
Last updated: Mon, 20 Sep 2010 11:22:11 GMT

User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.6.10

*** Extensions (enabled: 24, disabled: 0; total: 24)
1Password extension for Firefox 3 3.4.2 
Adblock Plus 1.2.2 
Add Bookmark Here ² 3.6.20100818 
Add to Search Bar 2.0 
Combine Buttons 0.6b7work 
DownThemAll! 1.1.10 
Easy DragToGo 1.1.2.4 
feedly 2.15 
Find Toolbar Tweaks 2.2.0 
Firebug 1.5.4 
FlashGot 1.2.1.31 
gleeBox 1.6 
Greasemonkey 0.8.20100408.6 
InfoLister 0.10.3 
It's All Text! 1.4.1 
Locationbar² 1.0.5 
Session Manager 0.6.8.3 
Speed Dial 0.9.5.6 
Tab Mix Lite 3.6.6 
tab-counter 0.2 
Tabby 1.0.4 
Tree Style Tab 0.10.2010080802 
Web Developer 1.1.8 
Xmarks 3.8.6
```

I tried to disable `Add Bookmark Here ²` but that did not solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Please try running in 'safe mode' to rule in/out your extensions (and other common identifiable factors) as the cause.

Comment: I ran Firefox in safe mode and everything worked perfectly thus confirming that the issue comes from an add-on.

Comment: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Troubleshooting+extensions+and+themes#The_problem_does_not_occur_in_Safe_Mode